# Lukasiewicz Logic Tautology

Tags: fuzzy-logic

Suppose a statement form $\varphi$ always has value T or U. Show $\varphi$ is a classical tautology.

Comment: This question is quite badly formulated. What is T? What is U? Do you mean first-order or just propositional?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Comment: Did you write out the truth table?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that a statement $\varphi$ of propositional logic (using only $\wedge$, $\vee$ and $\to$) is not a propositional tautology in classical logic. It follows that some row of the truth table for $\varphi$ has value $F$.

Now, consider the truth table of $\varphi$ in [Łukasiewicz three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), which is called Kleene logic on the Wikipedia page. The key observation is that Łukasiewicz three-valued logic agrees with classical logic on classical logic input. In other words, if all the propositional variables of $\varphi$ are given classical T/F values, then the truth value of $\varphi$ will agree with the classical logic value. Thus, since $\varphi$ had a classical row with value $F$, the very same row will have value F in the Łukasiewicz truth table of $\varphi$, contrary to the assumption that $\varphi$ had only values T or U.

Comment: The Wikipedia page actually has the correct table for Lukasiewicz three-valued logic.